# Поиск в строке сторки

Tags: php, строки

Как из строки $strint получить подстроку `$str`, содержащую искомое слово(а)? Искомое надо пометить тегом `<b></b>`. На экран нужно вывести несколько слов перед словом, которое ищется (если есть), само слово(а), несколько слов после (если есть).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но имелось ввиду немного другое.
Из большого текста надо найти одну подстроку и вернуть её вместе с некоторой частью текста. Например из всего романа "Война и мир" найти упоминание слова "Пьер" и вытащить одно предложение. Соответственно "Пьер" может стоять в начале, в конце или в середине.
Честно уже 2й день бьюс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$str = 'Как из строки ололо Получить подстроку трололо содержащую искомое слово(ааамв).';
$find = 'получить';
foreach($exp = explode(' ', $str) as $k => $v) {
  if ( mb_strtolower($find) == mb_strtolower($v) ) {
    echo $exp[$k - 2] . ' ' . $exp[$k - 1] . ' <b>' . $v . '</b> ' . $exp[$k + 1] . ' ' . $exp[$k + 2];
  }
}
```

**Результат:**

> строки ололо **Получить** подстроку трололо

Да-да, плюсуем :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Как из строки $strint получить подстроку $str содержащую искомое слово(а).';
$srch = 'получить';
$s = explode(' ', $str);
for($i = 0, $il = sizeof($s); $i < $il; ++$i){
    if($s[$i] == $srch){
        //нашли. надо echo'нуть
    }
}
```